# How do I fully migrate post images from one WordPress site to another?

Tags: migration, export

I know WordPress has a built-in tool for exporting content, but this does not actually export images associated with each post...it only exports an XML file. How do I actually export images in each post and upload them to my new WordPress site?

Answer (score 1):

The XML file you export will include *references* to the images, including a full URL. If the assets are actually available at that URL when you *import* the XML file, WordPress will automatically download them and add them to your new site's media library.

This gets tricky if the site you're importing *from* isn't publicly available via http. If that's the case, you can move the assets to someplace that is publicly available, and find-replace the relevant domains in the XML file before importing.

What you won't get (at least, I don't know how) is a bundle of content and files in a single package. You might try looking for a plugin that does this, but I couldn't find one with a cursory search.

Comment: Did you already find a solution? At the moment I manually export the media-Folder /wp-content/uploads